# Can every 2NF relation be made into 3NF relation?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database

Can each and every relation which is in `2NF` be made into `3NF` with lossless join and dependency preservation?

Edit:

There is a relation `R` with set of functional dependencies `F`.   `R` is in `2NF` but not in `3NF`. Can we decompose relation `R` into smaller relation which are in `3NF` and have lossless join with dependency compostion? And can it be done each and every time?

Comment: Actually every relation can be converted into 3NF state.

Comment: `Can every 2NF relation be made into 3NF relation?` What you want to ask how to convert?

Comment: ask it here http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions to get better answers

Comment: "Actually every relation can be converted into 3NF state." @GrijeshChauhan I think I got my answer.

Comment: @vincentmathew yes every relation be converted into 3NF it may required to break that relation into related relations. Well if you think that got your answer then you can delete this question for time being ..read some more text if you feel can post a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **yes** - it can be done.

*Longer explanation.*

Let's say we have relation `R` which is between `x -> y`. Assuming that `R` isn't in 2NF, new relations `P` and `Q` **must** exist, where `P: x -> z` and `Q: z -> y` and `P`, `Q`  must not be *trivial*. Here `x`, `y`, `z` are corresponding functional entities (they are not *"columns"* in common case, they also may be *"set of columns"*, if speak in terms of SQL tables).

Let us assume also that `P` and `Q` have no transitive sub-relations (like `R` has) - i.e. they are in 3NF (otherwise that will change nothing, we'll just go deeper and repeat all again until found sub-relations which have no transitive sub-relations).

So we have:

```
R(x) = y,
P(x) = z,  => Q(P(x)) = y
Q(z) = y
```

That's by definition of transitive relation. So, `R` will be split into two relations `P` and `R` (because only `P` and `Q` are enough to establish relation `x -> y`, so `R` is redundant and can be replaced with `P` and `Q` with joining those two relations). Our `P` and `Q` are in 3NF, thus, we've got `R` converted to 3NF relations. In fact, **this is the work** which should be done when normalizing 2NF -> 3NF (i.e. find and resolve all transitive relations such way).